# X11 - Graphics Rendering Improvement

Tags: c, gcc, graphics, rendering, x11

I am currently rendering an array of unsigned integers to a 2D image on a window, however, it is far too slow for what I want to accomplish with it. Here is my code:

```
int x = 0;
int y = 0;

GC gc;
XGCValues gcv;
gc = XCreateGC(display, drawable, GCForeground, &gcv);

while (y < height) {
    while (x < width) {
            XSetForeground(display, gc, AlphaBlend(pixels[(width*y)+x], backcolor));
            XDrawPoint(display, drawable, gc, x, y);
            x++;
    }
    x = 0;
    y++;
}

XFlush(display);
```

I was wondering if anyone show me a much faster method for doing this while still using my unsigned integer array as the base image to draw to the window as well as keeping it within the X11 API. I want to keep it as freestanding as possible. I don't want to use OpenGL, SDL or any other extra graphics libraries I do not need. Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think that using `XImage` could answer your need: see  https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/graphics/images.html

```
XImage * s_image;

void init(...)
{
    /* data linked to image, 4 bytes per pixel */
    char *data = calloc(width * height, 4);
    /* image itself */
    s_image = XCreateImage(display, 
        DefaultVisual(display, screen),
        DefaultDepth(display, screen), 
        ZPixmap, 0, data, width, height, 32, 0);
}

void display(...)
{
    /* fill the image */    
    size_t offset = 0;
    y = 0;
    while (y < height) {  
        x = 0;
        while (x < width) {
            XPutPixel(s_image, x, y, AlphaBlend((pixels[offset++], backcolor));
            x++;
        }    
        y++;
    }

    /* put image on display */
    XPutImage(display, drawable, cg, s_image, 0, 0, 0, 0, width, height);

    XFlush(display);
}
```

Comment: `XPutPixel` is of course faster than `XDrawPoint` but to be really fast one has to manipulate the pixels directly. See e.g. [this](ftp://ftp.ccp4.ac.uk/ccp4/7.0/unpacked/checkout/gdk-pixbuf-2.28.1/contrib/gdk-pixbuf-xlib/gdk-pixbuf-xlib-drawable.c) for an example of direct pixel manipulation. It's not pretty.

Comment: It works much faster! I will definitely take a look at this code file you attached, thank you.